# Groupby Date, reformatting my dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with multiple dates and counts against each date. Dates can occur multiple times. I grouped the data to plot a time series using:

```
timeseries = df[['date','count']].groupby(['date']).sum().reset_index()
```

Which lets me visualize what I need, but then when I try to view the exact values using:

```
timeseries.sort('count', ascending=False)['count'][:5]
```

The dates are printed in an indexed fashion:

```
Date    Count
1695    1529
1349    1013
1692     956
998      637
997      636
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Seems I am doing something basic incorrectly which leads me to lose the date value and maintain an index instead.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data before you create `timeseries` that you can post?

Comment: Solved: I should not have been using the `.reset_index()`in my groupby statement

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem, requires you to understand the difference between a columned named "date", and an index named "Date".  Then, your object types of the date column, need to be datetime-like.

Also, your date column may need converting, try using http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html

And, you shouldn't need to reset the index at the end.